# Points earned from approved edits persist after merging of accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, suggested-edits, merge-accounts

This is in regards to [this account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8848/okj) on Math.SE.

I saw a suggested edit to one of the questions the user posted, and since it looks reasonable, I approved it. Only afterwards did I realize that the two accounts are duplicate accounts. After merging the two duplicate accounts, the two reputation points earned from having a suggested edit approved still persists. Is this by design? (I did also manually trigger a rep recalc.)

Comment: I can see mechanically why it'd be by design - it still was a suggested edit that had to get approved, regardless of the final relation between the suggester and the question. Corner case as it may be, it can also be manually invoked, so I think it's something that could probably use some fixing.

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about suggested edits where the owner of the post and the editor were both the same user *after* the merge?

Comment: @Jon Check out [revision 3 of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/32411/revisions).

Comment: @Grace: Ah yes, thanks. I forgot the revision history specifies suggested edits now. It blends in so well.

Comment: @Jon Them coming from the same user certainly doesn't help in their location, haha ♪

Comment: I just ran into this situation today. @GraceNote any word from on high regarding if this will ever get fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This glitch no longer happens.  In the recalc that happens after the merge that +2 is assigned to no one, so the newly merged user does not reap the benefits of the cross-voting with themselves (the same way we remove it for up/down votes and bounties).