# Account merge may lead to user suggesting edits on own posts

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Points earned from approved edits persist after merging of accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87109/points-earned-from-approved-edits-persist-after-merging-of-accounts)

It is not uncommon for new users to lose their accounts and edit their posts with a new account, often with the same name and gravatar. I always flag these to be merged by moderator. After the merge, this leads to an edit suggestion by the same user who owns the post, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/35317
In addition, the merged user has 2 extra reputation points for editing his/her own question.

This may be a too small or uncommon bug to fix, but it may cause some confusion on how editing works for new users, or confusion when reviewing the revision list, specially with no indication a merge happened.